# How does malware performs a UDP hole punch?

Tags: malware, nat

I want to know how do malware like ZeroAccess hole punch the network without using a external server?

Or do they just mainly infect non-NAT users? Does that mean all NAT users are safe?

Comment: The core of your question is: does NAT protect my network? The core of the answer is of course not because it isn't its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how do malwares like ZeroAccess hole punch the network without using a external server?

ZeroAccess uses a P2P structure with no single central server. While most of the nodes can be behind a NAT some super nodes need to be not behind a NAT so that they can be reached from the other nodes (behind NAT) and relay communications. That means the nodes behind NAT simply open a connection from inside to any of the external super nodes and using this connection data can be sent back to the node. This is  the usual way of how P2P networks work and not specific to ZeroAccess.

[This paper from Sophos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/medialibrary/PDFs/technical%20papers/Sophos_ZeroAccess_Botnet.pdf) describes ZeroAccess and their communication model in more detail.

Comment: @danielAzuelos: fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can look first at what [STUN](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3489) is. Afterwards, you can use a [library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23481/Stunner-A-STUN-Library-and-Client) and try it out.

From the rfc:

> 1. Applicability Statement
>
>    This protocol is not a cure-all for the problems associated with
>      NAT.    It does not enable incoming TCP connections through NAT.  It
>      allows    incoming UDP packets through NAT, but only through a subset
>      of    existing NAT types.  In particular, STUN does not enable
>      incoming UDP    packets through symmetric NATs (defined below), which
>      are common in    large enterprises.  STUN's discovery procedures are
>      based on    assumptions on NAT treatment of UDP; such assumptions may
>      prove    invalid down the road as new NAT devices are deployed.  STUN
>      does not    work when it is used to obtain an address to communicate
>      with a peer    which happens to be behind the same NAT.  STUN does not
>      work when the    STUN server is not in a common shared address realm. 
>      For a more    complete discussion of the limitations of STUN, see
>      Section 14.